# Swift | Horizontal List

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, swiftui-list, horizontallist

I tried to make an horizontal list, but when I add on delete property it doesn't work.

```
var body: some View{
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    Section(
                            header: Text("Fruits")) {
                            ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                                Text(fruit.capitalized)
                            }
                            .onDelete(perform: delete)
                        }
                }
            }
                
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("Ejemplo")
        .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton())
    }
}

func delete(indexSet: IndexSet){
    fruits.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
}
```

[image: Here it works]
[image: Here it doesn't]

Comment: Bad question and description. your `onDelete` was always there even in the first view. It's not about `onDelete`. You changed the entire UI.

Comment: Remove the inner ScrollView you likely have conflicting gestures. You can't have swipe to scroll and swipe to delete in the same direction.